# Problems opening window CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm following [this tutorial for cross-platform game dev](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKH0QdYnI6AnUW3V3xeUuIxr0nyE9j61h), which is exactly what I want to do. However, I am not able to open a window.
My code structure:

```
build
external
    engine
        external
            glfw
            glm
        include
            template_engine
                platform
                    window.h
                engine.h
                service_locator.h
        src
            platform
                glfw_window.h
                glfw_window.cpp
            engine.cpp
        CMakeLists.txt
src
    main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

window.h:

```
#pragma once

class Window
{
public:
    virtual void OpenWindow() = 0;
    virtual bool Update() = 0;
};
```

engine.h:

```
#pragma once

struct TemplateEngine
{
    static void Init();
};
```

service_locator.h (slightly modified from the tutorial, should still work):

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <template_engine/platform/window.h>

class ServiceLocator
{
public:
    static inline const std::unique_ptr<Window>& GetWindow() { return _window; }

    static inline void Provide(Window* window)
    {
        if(_window == nullptr)
        {
            _window = std::unique_ptr<Window>(window);
        }
    }

private:
    static inline std::unique_ptr<Window> _window = nullptr;
}
```

glfw_window.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <template_engine/platform/window.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class CustomWindow : public Window
{
public:
    CustomWindow();

    virtual void OpenWindow() override;
    virtual bool Update() override;

private:
    GLFWwindow* _window;
};
```

glfw_window.cpp:

```
#include "glfw_window.h"

CustomWindow::CustomWindow()
{
    _window = nullptr;
}

void CustomWindow::OpenWindow()
{
    glfwInit();

    _window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "template engine window", nullptr, nullptr);
}

bool CustomWindow::Update()
{
    glfwPollEvents();

    return glfwWindowShouldClose(_window);
}
```

engine.cpp:

```
#include <template_engine/engine.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <template_engine/service_locator.h>

#include "platform/glfw_window.h"

void TemplateEngine::Init()
{
    std::cout << "Initializing window" << std::endl;
    
    ServiceLocator::Provide(new CustomWindow());
}
```

external/engine/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(template_cpp_engine VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

# add external libraries
add_subdirectory(external/glm)
add_subdirectory(external/glfw)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} 
            src/engine.cpp 
            src/platform/glfw_window.cpp
            src/platform/glfw_window.h)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        glm
    PRIVATE
        glfw
    )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        glm
    PRIVATE
        glfw
    )
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <template_engine/engine.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <template_engine/service_locator.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    
    TemplateEngine::Init();

    ServiceLocator::GetWindow()->OpenWindow();

    while(!ServiceLocator::GetWindow()->Update())
    {
        
    }
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(template_cpp_application VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

add_subdirectory(external/engine)

# template_cpp_application.exe
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} template_cpp_engine)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE template_cpp_engine)
```

I'm still fairly inexperienced, but this looks like it should work to me, and it worked in the tutorial. However, I get some errors whenever I try to build this program:

```
[{
    "resource": "/D:/Dev/CMake Template/external/engine/src/engine.cpp",
    "owner": "cmake-build-diags",
    "code": "C2061",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "syntax error: identifier 'CustomWindow' [D:\\Dev\\CMake Template\\build\\external\\engine\\template_cpp_engine.vcxproj]",
    "source": "MSVC",
    "startLineNumber": 13,
    "startColumn": 33,
    "endLineNumber": 13,
    "endColumn": 33
}]

[{
    "resource": "/d:/Dev/CMake Template/external/engine/src/platform/glfw_window.h",
    "owner": "cmake-build-diags",
    "code": "C2236",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "unexpected token 'class'. Did you forget a ';'? [D:\\Dev\\CMake Template\\build\\external\\engine\\template_cpp_engine.vcxproj]",
    "source": "MSVC",
    "startLineNumber": 6,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 6,
    "endColumn": 1
}]

[{
    "resource": "/d:/Dev/CMake Template/external/engine/src/platform/glfw_window.h",
    "owner": "cmake-build-diags",
    "code": "C2059",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "syntax error: ':' [D:\\Dev\\CMake Template\\build\\external\\engine\\template_cpp_engine.vcxproj]",
    "source": "MSVC",
    "startLineNumber": 6,
    "startColumn": 20,
    "endLineNumber": 6,
    "endColumn": 20
}]

[{
    "resource": "/d:/Dev/CMake Template/external/engine/src/platform/glfw_window.h",
    "owner": "cmake-build-diags",
    "code": "C2059",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "syntax error: 'public' [D:\\Dev\\CMake Template\\build\\external\\engine\\template_cpp_engine.vcxproj]",
    "source": "MSVC",
    "startLineNumber": 6,
    "startColumn": 22,
    "endLineNumber": 6,
    "endColumn": 22
}]

[{
    "resource": "/d:/Dev/CMake Template/external/engine/src/platform/glfw_window.h",
    "owner": "cmake-build-diags",
    "code": "C2143",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "syntax error: missing ';' before '{' [D:\\Dev\\CMake Template\\build\\external\\engine\\template_cpp_engine.vcxproj]",
    "source": "MSVC",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 7,
    "endColumn": 1
}]

[{
    "resource": "/d:/Dev/CMake Template/external/engine/src/platform/glfw_window.h",
    "owner": "cmake-build-diags",
    "code": "C2447",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "'{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) [D:\\Dev\\CMake Template\\build\\external\\engine\\template_cpp_engine.vcxproj]",
    "source": "MSVC",
    "startLineNumber": 7,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 7,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
```

I've already checked all the obvious problems, and was able to solve some problems in  service_locator.h using Phind, but I can't figure out how to fix these errors, which all seem to be related. if it's any help, here's my tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-std=c++23",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

and my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22000.0",
            "compilerPath": "cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c23",
            "cppStandard": "c++23",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am curious, have you tried to read the error messages? The answer is there!

Comment: what do you think `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE template_cpp_engine)` does?

Comment: @273k I understand that you're trying to help, but if you could tell me what the problem is and where in the error message it says that, it would be a lot more helpful. I already found the answer, but this vague answer did not help.

Comment: @user I really don't know what it does, I just copied it from the tutorial. I agree that it doesn't look right, but it's not what's causing my errors.

Comment: Don't study C++ with video tutorials of unknown authors with unmkonwn skills. You waste you time. Invest it in one of the books in [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Reading errors is one of must have skills of successful developers. Try to read them carefully. The hint: the answer is in the second JSON entry. Just trust me, if you fix the error yourself, you get more profit than you get a ready fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ServiceLocator` class definition is missing a semicolon after its closing curly brace. I'm guessing that's what 273K was referencing? The second error message says that the compiler didn't expect to see the `class` keyword for your `CustomWindow` class and that a semicolon is probably missing. I'm guessing if we could see a full trace of what source file is being compiled when that error is found, it would be in the compilation of engine.cpp, where you `#include <template_engine/service_locator.h>` and then `#include "platform/glfw_window.h"` right after.